# SQL Server 2008 Express CONCAT() doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making switch from MySQL to SQL Server 2008 Express and can't seem to find a CONCAT()-esque function.  I have two columns I'm trying to combine into a string and find unique combinations.

```
id1          id2
001          abc1
002          qrs5
003          qrs5
003          abc1
...           ...
```

When I try the following:

```
  select id1, id2, concat(id1,  ", ", id2) as combo1
  FROM db1
  group by combo1
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
>   'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Next version will have a `CONCAT` function](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/concat-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: It is probably worth noting that `concat` in MySQL [returns `null` when any argument is `null`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), while the sought-for MS SQL `concat` [converts nulls to empty strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) before concatenation and never returns `null`, so even though we do have it now, it may not be used for the OP's goal of porting MySQL to MSSQL.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Maybe something like,

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1, id2, id1 + ', ' + id2
```

would that work?

Comment: Don't think so.  There are overlaps in id1 and id2.  I need the combined string to be unique, not just id1.

Comment: @screechOwl: What Bassam is suggesting is merely a replacement for `CONCAT()`. It does the same thing: `+` means concatenation in T-SQL when the operands are strings.

Comment: I am looking up CONCAT and it doesn't seem to be detecting uniqueness on it's own.. in your sample data put some example of what your no-unique input could be, and what you need the result to be maybe we can help you out

Comment: ok, thanks, i'm still getting used to the less verbose syntax for SQLS.  That worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: i think we can use it instead of CONCAT() function right...?

Answer (score 26):

You can use CONCAT in SQL 2008 (if you REALLY want) by wrapping in brackets

```
{fn CONCAT(id1,id2)} AS combo1
```

NOTE: CONCAT only takes two arguments, so you must nest them if you wish to concatenate more than two strings:

```
{fn CONCAT(id1,{fn CONCAT(id2,id3)})} AS combo2
```

Comment: This works. But what does it mean actually? And how does it affect a 2012 version, if used like this?

Comment: It is ODBC syntax more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fasyf1c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), I am not sure on 2012.

Comment: note that this only supports two arguments, not arbitary length

Answer (score 3):

`CONCAT`doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008, it is new since SQL Server 2012.

You could use instead:

```
select id1, id2, id1 +  ", " + id2 as combo1
FROM db1
group by combo1
```