# (Select FirstName + ' ' + LastName from Members gives error Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, correlated-subquery

```
Select FirstName + ' ' + LastName from Members
```

Gives error:

> Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict.

But it works fine when I take `FirstName` and `LastName` in separate columns like

```
Select FirstName, LastName From Members
```

I want to pick First and Last name in one column

Comment: Try looking into this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861782/sql-server-error-implicit-conversion-of-because-the-collation-of-the-value-is-u

Comment: [This link may help you as you are using SQL 2008][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547737/sql-server-2008-express-concat-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have different collation within the same table - very unusual

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  FirstName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' ' 
    + LastName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS FullName
FROM Members
```

If this works, I suggest you change collation to be the same for FirstName and LastName rather than correcting your query.

This is an example of how to change collation:

```
ALTER TABLE Members 
  ALTER COLUMN LastName 
    varchar(20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL
```

Comment: yep this works ... but what is collate ? why it occurs on this table ?

Comment: @mike here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538732/what-does-collation-mean) describing collation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select CAST(FirstName AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(LastName AS VARCHAR)from Members 
or
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),FirstName) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),LastName )from Members
```

Comment: what is the data type of firstname and lastname column in table ??

Comment: varchar(20) both fields and not null have characters

Comment: try using by adding COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT after the column

Answer (score 0):

Look what collation is on your tempdb. You can see it in the properties.

This collation you have to add to your Statements to change the collation of the field temporary.

example:

Your database has a collation "Latin1_General_CS_AS", tempdb's collation is "Latin1_General_CI_AS" your statement has to look like this, because the dynamic SQL will process in tempdb

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Select concat(concat(FirstName , ' '), LastName) as final from Members
```

Comment: 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: im using SQL server 2008

Comment: concat is sqlserver 2012

Comment: Then we can go by using COLLATE function in sql